# How do we calculate the charging time of a Li-ion battery if we used a fast charger?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, calculation

Consider a rechargeable 7.4 V, 5000 mAh Li-ion battery.

If we were to fast charge this battery, what would be the charging time?

Although it is known that the general equation for charging time is:

***Charging time = Battery Capacity(Ah)/Applied Current(A)***

How could we be sure as the fast charging of Li-ion/Li-po battery happens in stages (CC-CV)?

It is also known that in fast charging the battery will be fast charged up to a certain percentage of the total Battery capacity (Ah), and then the charging rate decreases eventually.

Any charger capable of delivering an output power of 10 W or more can be considered as a fast charger.

So wouldn't the general equation given above fall short when we consider fast chargers? If no, how? And if yes, what should be the new equation or set of equations?

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: 2 hours.

Regardless of battery specs, for the sake of battery longevity, a Li-ion battery should not be charged any faster than over 2 hours. That's an initial specific current of slightly more than 0.5 C (to account for the CV time), which is considered reasonable for all Li-ion chemistries (LCO, NMC, LFP) and formats (pouch, cylindrical, prismatic). The exception is LTO (Titatane) cells, which can be charged much faster with no ill effects.

(By the way: "LiPo" is just a Li-ion cell, usually LCO, in a pouch format.)

You *can* charge faster, but that is generally at the expense of cell health: fast charging (especially at low temperatures) reduces cell capacity and may eventually result in dendrite formation and finally spectacular failure.

Having said that:

1. Some charging algorithms that are perfectly tailored to a specific cell can charge that cell more quickly without entering regions of fast degradation
2. Some Li-ion cells were designed to handle charging at a specific current higher than 0.5 C without degrading too much

In your case, I doubt either of those apply, so my answer remains:

```
If you care about the health of your battery: 2 hours.
```

Answer (score 0):

That equation sets the charging time. It holds as long as the battery is new.

With time the capacity decreases but unfortunately it's not that easy to estimate the exact value of that capacity.

To answer your question:

That equation holds if you know the exact value of the capacity.